# ReCaptcha plugin in a visual studio webpart?

Tags: 2010, form

I have created a visual webpart in Visual Studio 2010. I am using SP2010. In this webpart I have a form with a button. I would like to add reCaptcha on this form. I am talking about the original reCaptcha ASP.NET plugin: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/aspnet?hl=nl

Is it possible to implement this reCaptcha in a webpart? What do I need to do with the recaptcha dll? Do I need to add a safetype in the web.config for this dll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add additional assemblies in your Package, when you double click your Package file -> go to Advance section.. following screen:

[image: Package]

Here you can add additional dll's and mark Safe Controls and define the location either GAC or Web Application folder (bin folder)

Comment: thank you. I have add the dll to the advanced tab of my package under additional assemblies. I have checked "safe controls".

Answer (score 0):

When using third party dlls you need to add them in GAC and add safe control entries.